# Update DIV content with different API parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsonp

I'm trying to update the contents of a div after the DOM has loaded.

The contents are being loaded from an API which loads different content based on what parameter values are passed.

The contents load fine to start with.  But I have an option for a user to either just load the 'Sales' or 'Rentals' properties so I have an onClick function to update the parameters of the API.

Here is my code

```
var url = "http://api.zoopla.co.uk/api/v1/property_listings.js";
var key = "APIKEY";
var branch = "7103";
var ajaxURL = url + "?branch_id=" + branch + "&api_key=" + key;

$('#rentals a').click(function (evt) {
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    ajaxURL += link;
    $("#main").load('#main');
    evt.preventDefault();

});

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'jsonp',
    url: ajaxURL,
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data.listing, function (i, property) {
            $("#main").append('<h3>' + property.displayable_address + '</h3><p>' + property.description + '<br /> <img src="' + property.image_url + '" /> </p>')
        });
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Sorry, I can't get the feed");
    }
}); // end GET
```

Its this code here I can't get wo to work

```
$('#rentals a').click(function (evt) {
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    ajaxURL += link;
    $("#main").load('#main');
    evt.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: What do you expect that code to do?  What does it do instead?

Comment: When the page loads it displays all the properties from both sales and rentals.  When the user clicks the 'Rentals' link, I want the page to update and just display the properties for rent instead.  So i'm trying to change the ajaxURL and append the perimeter "?listing_status=rent"

Answer (score 0):

The .load() function is expecting a url to be passed to it, but you're passing the same selector (#main). It should probably be something more like this:

```
$('#main').load(ajaxURL);
```